# Tensorflow: How can I convolve image with custom constant filter

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution, tensor

I have 3 5x5 filters I want to convolve on a grayscale image (shape [nx,ny,1]) input. I have preset hardcoded values each of these 5x5 filters need to be and I don't want them to be "learned" by my model but just be a constant operation.

How do I achieve this?

I was looking into using tf.nn.conv2d() and it says its filters need to be of shape [height, width, input, output] so I tried to use tf.constant() to create a tensor for my filters of shape [5,5,1,3] (so 3 filters of shape 5x5 applied to an input with 1 channel) but the results from tf.constant() did not look right. It came out like this:

```
 [[[[ -5   7  -12]]

   [[  21  0   2]]

   [[ -6   9  -6]]

   [[  2  -2   8]]

   [[-6   4  -1]]]


  [[[  2  -6   8]]

   [[ -6   2  -1]]

   [[  2  -2   2]]

   [[ -1   1   5]]

   [[  4   3   2]]]

 ...etc
```

which does not look like the shape of 3 5x5 filters.

If I use tf.constant() with the shape as [1,3,5,5] I get this:

```
[[[[ -5   7  -12   21  0]
   [  2  -6   9  -6   2]
   [ -2   8 -6   4  -1]
   [  2  -6   8  -6   2]
   [ -1   2  -2   2  -1]]

  [[  1   5   4   3   2]
   [  4   0  -2   0   4]
   [  2  -1   7  -3   5]
   [  -1   0  -1   0  -1]
   [  5   0   9   0   5]]

   ...etc
```

which *does* look like 5x5 filters but it's not the correct shape taken in by tf.nn.conv2d()

so I'm confused by this mismatch and don't know what the right thing to do is.

Comment: Don't worry about what the tensor looks like when you display it, just match TensorFlow's expectation

Answer (score 2):

It's better not to worry about how the filters look like. Just keep track of the shape to make sure they make sense.

Here is an example to apply 2 Sobel filters to an image:

```
from skimage import data
img = np.expand_dims(data.camera(), -1)
img = np.expand_dims(img, 0)  # shape: (1, 512, 512, 1)

sobel_x = np.array([[-0.25, -0.2 ,  0.  ,  0.2 ,  0.25],
                   [-0.4 , -0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.5 ,  0.4 ],
                   [-0.5 , -1.  ,  0.  ,  1.  ,  0.5 ],
                   [-0.4 , -0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.5 ,  0.4 ],
                   [-0.25, -0.2 ,  0.  ,  0.2 ,  0.25]])

sobel_y = np.array([[-0.25, -0.4 , -0.5 , -0.4 , -0.25],
                   [-0.2 , -0.5 , -1.  , -0.5 , -0.2 ],
                   [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
                   [ 0.2 ,  0.5 ,  1.  ,  0.5 ,  0.2 ],
                   [ 0.25,  0.4 ,  0.5 ,  0.4 ,  0.25]])

filters = np.concatenate([[sobel_x], [sobel_y]])  # shape: (2, 5, 5)
filters = np.expand_dims(filters, -1)  # shape: (2, 5, 5, 1)
filters = filters.transpose(1, 2, 3, 0)  # shape: (5, 5, 1, 2)

# Convolve image
ans = tf.nn.conv2d((img / 255.0).astype('float32'),
                   filters,
                   strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                   padding='SAME')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    ans_np = sess.run(ans)  # shape: (1, 512, 512, 2)

filtered1 = ans_np[0, ..., 0]
filtered2 = ans_np[0, ..., 1]
```

The image is correctly convolved with the 2 filters and the resulting images look like:

```
plt.matshow(filtered1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
plt.matshow(filtered2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first case seems to be correctly showing filters of shape `[5, 5, 1, 3]`. Take a look at the number of square brackets - tensorflow is showing the 4th dimension across the horizontal of each of those little boxes, and the 2nd dimension down the vertical. (The 3rd has dimensionality of 1, so there's no point in showing that)